# After Update Ubuntu PDF files restart Comp

Tags: updates, pdf

After I update Laptop to UbuntuMate 22.04, I cannot open PDF files. As soon as I click on the PDF file my Laptop restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall Document Viewer (*evince*). Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge evince
sudo apt install evince
```